# Keeping head reference while traversing Linked Lists?

Tags: java, reference, linked-list

I'm revising Linked Lists and in the book I'm using they suggest the following code to search for a specific value:

```
public ListElement<Integer> find( ListElement<Integer> head, int data ){
   ListElement<Integer> elem = head;
   while( elem != null && elem.value() != data ){
       elem = elem.next();
   }
   return elem;
}
```

But, cannot we iterate on `head` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can - but then it would be a somewhat misleading piece of code. If I look at a variable called `head`, I'd expect it to be the head of a list - whereas if I do:

```
head = head.next();
```

... then `head` refers to something which *isn't* the head of the list. It's always worrying when a variable name implies something that isn't true. It would technically work, but it would be a bad idea.

I would personally write the code more like this:

```
public ListElement<Integer> find(ListElement<Integer> head, int data) {
    for (ListElement<Integer> current = head;
           current != null;
           current = current.next()) {
        if (current.value == data) {
            return current;
        }
    }
    // No entry found
    return null;
}
```

That way the "not found" case is more naturally distinct from the "found" case - it would be easier to change it to throw an exception if the value isn't found, for example.

Comment: Uh, okay, that makes sense. I thought there was a core reason for that and I didn't understand references... Thanks!